# Laravel eloquent increment calculated percentage on update

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have an integer column, and need to increment value on a selected rows, with his percentage.

I'm trying to do some like this:

```
    $value = $request->percentage / 100;
    $lineaCalendario  = Calendar::where('rate_id', $idRate)
                                        ->whereIn('date', $dates) 
                                        ->increment('price', DB::raw('price')*$value);
```

This don't work.

> Unsupported operand types: float *
> Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression

But I can't find how to do it..

Comment: You are trying to mix a query build with a PHP calculation. DB::raw() returns an expression so you cannot multiply it by $value

Comment: Yes, I understand, but how can I make an increase of X% at a price directly in the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `update` method instead of `increment` and do your multiplication of the price * `$value` in the DB::raw() query directly. Indeed, you can't multiple your value by an expression:

```
Calendar::query()
    ->where('rate_id', $idRate)
    ->whereIn('date', $dates)
    ->update([
        'price' => DB::raw("price + (price * ${value})")
    ])
```

**Notice**: As described in the official documentation of Laravel:

```
Raw statements will be injected into the query as strings, 
so you should be extremely careful to avoid creating SQL injection vulnerabilities.
```

Comment: Actually, I need to add the percentage result. For example, if the price is 100 and the percentage to add is 10%, the updated price should be 110.

Comment: Have you tried this solution? It should works.

Comment: Yes, I have tried it, if the price is 100, and the increment is 10%, the result is 10, this is what you are inserting, and it should be the increment of 10 plus 100. Ok, works with: 'price' => DB::raw("price + price* ${value}") :)

Comment: Ohhh OK, it's just your calculation. I take it from your question. I'll update the response.